# Django form with choice field not providing None as a choice

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a choice field in a form defined as

```
REFERRAL_CHOICES = (
    (None, 'Please choose'),
    ('search', 'From a search engine'),
    ('social', 'From a social network'),
)
referral_source = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=REFERRAL_CHOICES
)
```

I also have a `clean_company_size` function which checks if the field is set to a good value:

```
def clean_company_size(self):
    company_size = self.cleaned_data.get('company_size', None)
    if company_size is None:
        raise ValidationError('Please select a company size')

    return company_size
```

If I add a `or company_size == 'None'` condition to the above None check, all works well. However, I am curious why the None value is being cast to a string. What is the best way of accomplishing a default prompts in a choice field and having that field be required?

Comment: All POST and GET variables, as well as Select HTML tag values are initially sent as strings. Django converts them to -say- int when it is deductable from the model. In your case it is not possible to distinguish a "None" string from a "None" object, they are both possible values. You may prefer using "" instead of None in your REFERRAL_CHOICHES

Comment: Great explanation. If you make this an answer, I will up-vote it and accept it, as it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `POST` and `GET` variables, as well as `Select` HTML tag values are initially sent as strings. Django converts them to -say- `int` when it is deductable from the model. In your case it is not possible to distinguish a "None" string from a "None" object, they are both possible values. You may prefer using "" instead of `None` in your `REFERRAL_CHOICHES`

Comment: Though you are absolutely right, this feels like a bug in Django. In the backend, we send a None, we could expect to receive it back as None, and not 'None'...